# Excel VBA: Assign macro to commandbutton to create hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, commandbutton

I'm new and struggling with this function of hyperlinking.
I'm using a userform where I have a commandbutton.
I would like the commandbutton (when clicked) to create a hyperlink - basically, take me to the Insert Hyperlink window, where I can edit/assign my own hyperlinks.

what would the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

something like this ?

```
 Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show
 End Sub
```

Comment: I've just tried it, it doesn't work :(

Comment: what does not work ? is the Event not fired or does the Application....Show not work ? what's the Name of your button ? is it an activeX button or not ?

Comment: I clicked the commandbutton in the userform, and nothing happened - no error. Yes, it is ActiveX button

Comment: what is the Name of the button ?

Comment: The name is CommandButton1

Comment: then you have to rename the click handler to the buttonName .... you should really first understand how to handle a button click.

Comment: Hey Doktor - seems as though you're best with instant responses.
I would like the code to be able to take the user to the folder from which they must insert the hyperlink to a file as well as pre-populate the name of the hyperlink

Say for instance that the file location is: S:\Quality Assurance\Quality

The pre-populated file name should be: Drawing

So what modifications to my code would need to be made or is the above even possible?

Comment: i am not 100% sure, but i think you will have to write your own form for that. and use the Hyperlinks.add command -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff822490.aspx